# Cannot create ROS2 debian packages with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, debian, ros

I have a `ROS2` package and it is using `OpenCV 4.7.0`, which is installed from source.
I can build the package with `colcon-build --symlink-install` and also test it using `colcon-test`. The correct opencv version is found, which is `4.7.0`. But when I create .deb packets using `bloom-generate rosdebian...` it cannot find the `OpenCV 4.7.0` but references to `OpenCV 4.5.4`. This is a conflict between the versions so no `.deb` packaets are created. How do I make the `bloom-generate rosdebian` find the right version?

I do not understand why build and test can locate the right version mentioned in the `CMakeLists.txt` but not `bloom-generate`.

Note:

1. Everything worked well with OpenCV 4.5.4, because I was building it from source and also may be because 4.5.4 comes with Ubuntu 22.04 with "libopencv-dev" packet.
2. I just changed the version number and everything else is same.
3. I don't have any problem with any version while working on local machine, but this happends only in Git CD/CI pipeline inside the docker container, which has the same configuration as my local machine.

Thank you.